# Embedding a CMD terminal in a C# Winforms application

Tags: c#, process, createprocess

What I intend to do is build an application which, among other things, will have a command line embedded in it just like some IDEs do (something I find extremely useful).

This is the code that I have so far, do note that it's a Winforms project:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Process p = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();

        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            info.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            info.RedirectStandardError = true;
            info.UseShellExecute = false;
            info.CreateNoWindow = true;

            p.StartInfo = info;
            p.Start();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            using(StreamWriter sw = p.StandardInput) {
                if(sw.BaseStream.CanWrite) {
                    sw.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
                }
            }
            textBox2.Text = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            textBox3.Text = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
            p.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see there are 3 textboxes and one button:

- textbox1 is for entering the command
- textbox2 is for stdout
- textbox3 is for stderr

On to my problem:

I can only input *one* command because after executing it, my CMD window vanishes. I know it dies off because I've set `info.CreateNoWindow = false;` and it indeed vanishes and if I try to enter another command I get an exception.

**How would I go on about keeping my CMD window 'alive' so that I can use it as much as I please? In short I want to truly mimic CMD behavior.**

Feel free to ask for more information if something is not clear.

**Extra info/What I tried:**

I've tried adding `info.Attributes = "/K";` since I know that `/K` should keep the CMD alive. I've also read that `p.WaitForExit();` should keep the CMD alive, but from what I figured this is only for the purpose of reading the output. Needless to say, I do not need that since I'm already redirecting its output. Neither of these solutions work but it is entirely possible that I'm using them the wrong way.

I need that process alive so I can easily navigate using `cd` and executing a sequence of commands when needed, such as when accessing `ftp` or `mysql`. I know I can work around these two examples with parameters, but not for every application. In short, spawning a new process every time is not something I want. I want that CMD interface to be up at all times.

The cmd process dies after

```
using(StreamWriter sw = p.StandardInput) {
    if(sw.BaseStream.CanWrite) {
        sw.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
    }
}
```

But I cannot pinpoint why.

Comment: That `using` statement causes `p.StandardInput` to be disposed (`sw` is just a reference to it). Don't do that - dispose `p` instead (when you no longer need it).

Comment: @PieterWitvoet Thank you for your answer. So basically p gets disposed of when I leave the `using` scope? How would I go on about using the StreamWriter without the `using` statement? I have tried declaring the StreamWriter in the `Form1_Load` method and accessing the output `p.StandardOutput` afterwards, but my application hangs without any exception. Could you elaborate please?

Comment: Whatever you're `using` gets disposed at the end of the `using` block - so each time you enter a command your code is disposing the standard input of your process. You're essentially disposing part of an object and expecting it to continue working as it did before. Just remove that `using` statement. `sw` is not a new stream writer that you're responsible for - it's a reference to `p.StandardInput`. Disposing `p` will take care of disposing those stream writers for you.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet I've been experimenting using the StreamWriter without the `using` block while you were writing your last comment. The debugger clearly shows that the command is sent towards the process, but my application hangs when trying to read the output, a la `textBox2.Text = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();`. Needless to say, I get no output in my application. Here's the interesting thing though: if I manually close the CMD window (the spawned process), my application receives the output. But I cannot use the process any more since I closed it. Do you have any idea as to why this happens?

Comment: I assume `ReadToEnd` hangs because the stream doesn't end. Try peeking the stream before you read something.

Answer (score 0):

What CMD console provides is an interface to execute predefined functions (in System32 or in %PATH%). *Process* class also have same capabilities ,what you can do is as the user enters command text and presses return key in textbox2 (which can be multi-lined, black-background, white text) you can pass the command text to `Process p = new Process();`and append the result so it looks like single cmd session. Now before passing the whole command text we need to separate arguments (if any) which is text appearing after first space. Example:

```
SHUTDOWN /S /T 10
```

where Shutdown will be filename and /S /T 10 will be arguments.

Before executing set default directory of ProcessStartInfo:-

```
_processStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"%Path%";
```

Otherwise default will be System32 folder.

Comment: This is actually an idea that I also thought about and implemented it in a C++ app a while back. Unfortunately it's just a shadow of the real thing, a simulation, a workaround. Not an actual solution. This is exactly why I'm rewriting a similar application in C#. But thanks for your input, I will keep this as a last resort.